# telnet - how to know when to give control back to the user

Tags: c#, .net, telnet

To begin with, why I've written a Telnet client is not important.  It's my job and I have to do it.  So, on to my question...

My Telnet client is simple and allows for both interactive communication (used by a human) as well as automated communication (used by a program).  However, in order for my client to know when the server is done sending data so it can give control back to the user, I've had to hard code all of the possible command prompts for a given server into the client application.  For instance, I create a list of prompts and then pass this list to the client so it can watch for these in the data stream from the server.  When it sees that a data stream ends with one, it then gives control back to the user, who will enter a response or a command and send it.  The client then watches again for any of these prompts and so on.  The list could look like the following for a Telnet server running on CentOS:

```
private static void SetTerminalPrompts()
{
    prompts.Add("login: ");
    prompts.Add("Password: ");
    prompts.Add("]$ ");
    prompts.Add("]# ");
}
```

This would be used like:

```
response = telnetClient.ReceiveUntilPrompt(prompts);
```

And `public string ReceiveUntilPrompt(List<string> prompts)` simply reads the data stream watching for a prompt from the list.

The problem is watching for these prompts.  In a general case, the Telnet client will not know the server to which it is connecting.  And it seems silly to attempt to create a *complete* list of possible prompts by guessing all servers to which the client may ever connect (even though I've found several examples and posts that say just that).

What I would like to know is how do the Telnet clients that come with Windows or Linux know when to give control back to the user?  How do they know when the Telnet server is done sending data?

Comment: You could dig into the source code for any of the variety of open source telnet clients to try to solve your question.  PuTTY is certainly a popular one.  www.putty.org

Comment: @Cortright I've been doing this, but I forgot about PuTTY (not sure how I missed that one).  I'll look at it, too.